# Writing strings to plist file

Tags: swift, plist

I want to save an array to plist. Therefore, I've written the function above. But when I run it I got the error above.

```
var tasks = [String]()

func addTask(name: String){
    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Classes", ofType: "plist")
    let dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path!)
    dict?.setValue(name, forKey: "AppleDevice")
}
```

**Error:**

```
2015-09-12 21:37:52.383 SB Reminder[12433:2057713] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'
*** First throw call stack:
```

Comment: Hint: you presumably have an array as your tableview datasource. Arrays can write themselves and be created from a plist.

Comment: NSDictionary vs NSMutableDictionary.